# Jade equivalent for csrf token in Django

Tags: django, pug

how can I use the csrf_token in jade provided by Django?

I have tried

```
form(method="POST")
  input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value=csrf_token)
```

But it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
input(type='hidden', value='{{ csrf_token }}', name='csrfmiddlewaretoken')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pyjade and django, it looks like the code:

```
form(method="POST")
  input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value="{{ csrf_token }}")
```

or possibly:

```
form(method="POST")
  input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value='#{ csrf_token }')
```

should work, depending on your setup.